# How to telnet to an SMTP server from within with the context of an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, smtp, telnet, azure-web-app-service

I need to troubleshoot a connection from an application running in an Azure App Service to an external (non-Azure) SMTP server.

The SMTP server is, to all intents and purposes, a black-box which I do not control. I have been assured that it has been correctly configured to whitelist the Azure outgoing IP addresses. Despite this, the application is still unable to connect. The generic error is simply:

> Failure sending mail.

On a standard VM, I would just RDP into it and use `telnet` from the command line.

With the App Service, I am having to rely on the in-browser Kudu console, which does not support `telnet`.

How can I interactively test the connection to the SMTP server without relying on redeploying the application with test code to log trial-and-error attempts?

Comment: Use Kudu's PowerShell console. `Send-MailMessage` should give you a meaningful error message.

Comment: Have you tried using curl from the Kudu console?

Comment: @CSharpRocks I will - did not realise it was available.

Comment: @evilSnobu This sounds like a great option, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recall in past we used in Kudu console command: `tcpping smtp.testdomain.com:25` and it was a sufficient test.